# Instance method as function object

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods

I need to pass an instance method as an argument to a function:

```
class C(object):
    def m(self):
        print("m",self)

def f(l,b):
    for z in l:
        b(z)

x = C()

f([x], lambda c: c.m())
```

is there a better way than the `lambda`?

It appears that `f([x], C.m)` works too, but is this an accident or an official feature?

Comment: `C.m` will be a reference to an unbound method (as in no associated `self` instance).  Passing `<instance>.m` would work though.

Comment: @jedwards: I do not have the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller)

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> f([x], methodcaller('m'))
m <__main__.C object at 0x1317bbda0>
```

`methodcaller` returns a callable that will call a method on a given instance passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
f([x], C.m)
```

Here, `C.m` is the method without an instance.  It does the same thing as your lambda.  It is definitely an official and supported feature.